# WearableRecyclerView doesn't centre the list items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, watch

I've been trying for several days to make a list with the same effect that some Wear OS apps do, such as Google Play Store, where the list is shrinking the items that are disappearing and expanding the new items that are appearing:

[image]

I followed the Google Developers documentation, the problem is that when I apply the custom Layout Manager to it, the items don't stay centered for me, they look like this:

[image]

This is the code I used:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".ui.activity.HomeActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <androidx.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/wearable_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

```kotlin
private fun setupAdapter() {
    val homeOptionsAdapter = HomeOptionsAdapter(petList)
    val customScrollingLayoutCallback = CustomScrollingLayoutCallback()
    recyclerWearable.layoutManager = WearableLinearLayoutManager(
       this, 
       customScrollingLayoutCallback
    )
    recyclerWearable.isEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled = true
    recyclerWearable.adapter = homeOptionsAdapter
}
```

```kotlin
private const val MAX_ICON_PROGRESS = 2f

class CustomScrollingLayoutCallback : WearableLinearLayoutManager.LayoutCallback() {

    private var progressToCenter: Float = 0f

    override fun onLayoutFinished(child: View, parent: RecyclerView) {
        child.apply {
            // Figure out % progress from top to bottom
            val centerOffset = height.toFloat() / 2.0f / parent.height.toFloat()
            val yRelativeToCenterOffset = y / parent.height + centerOffset

            // Normalize for center
            progressToCenter = abs(0.5f - yRelativeToCenterOffset)
            // Adjust to the maximum scale
            progressToCenter = progressToCenter.coerceAtMost(MAX_ICON_PROGRESS)

            scaleX = 1 - progressToCenter.pow(2f)
            scaleY = 1 - progressToCenter.pow(2f)
        }
    }
}
```

I read that with the option setEdgeItemsCenteringEnabled the list was centered, but I don't see it centered, what can I do?

Comment: If you use compose in your project you could just use [ScalingLazyColumn](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/compose/lists) and get the scaling and transparency effects for free

Answer (score 0):

I have/had the same issue, this is the best work around I could get:

> Vid demostration: [video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FYKuFKVs7D_hldGjbeL3GGdzP-HKid2Q/view?usp=share_link)

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- OPTIONAL -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".Main"
    android:id="@+id/main">

<!-- REQUIRED-->
    <androidx.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<!-- OPTIONAL -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_shadow"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<!-- OPTIONAL -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_shadow"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**gradient_shadow.xml** //OPTIONAL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:centerX="100%"
        android:startColor="#DD000000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="-90"/>
</shape>
```

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="56sp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3sp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_design">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18sp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_main_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10sp"
        android:text="List item"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**list_design.item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/gray"></solid>
    <corners android:radius="50dp"/>
</shape>
```

**customScrollingLayoutCallback**

// I have this "math" from another app that I was design in javascript for smartphone a long time ago... I dont remember why each part, so, sorry, cant explain hahaha

//I just added the if part and alpha

```
public void onLayoutFinished(View child, RecyclerView parent) {
    int height_parent = parent.getHeight();

    float half_height_parent = (float) parent.getHeight() / 2;

    int child_max_width = parent.getWidth();

    float child_new_width = ((1 - Math.abs((child.getY() - half_height_parent + 45) / height_parent)) * height_parent);

    float equivalent_scale = child_new_width / child_max_width;

    child.setAlpha(equivalent_scale);

    if(child_new_width > (child_max_width * 0.63)) {
        child.setScaleX(0.96f);
        child.setScaleY(1);
    } else {
        child.setScaleX(equivalent_scale + 0.2f);
        child.setScaleY(0.98f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, the best solution would be to change the child width with "child_new_width", however I didnt find a way to do so, thats why I'm changing the scale in x... I change the scale in Y just to look a bit better.
Another thing, is that the scale changes suddently, I still havent figured out a way to change smoothly.
The reason why their code shows weird spaces between the items is because of the scalling in Y